# Entity Framework Core: loading nested entities for objects with variable nesting levels

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

In my project I have an entity called `Question` that has a property called `QuestionCategories` that is a collection of objects of type `QuestionCategory`:

```
public class Question : AuditEntity
{
    public long QuestionId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public byte Complexity { get; set; }
    public short QuestionTypeId { get; set; }
    public QuestionType QuestionType { get; set; }
    public ICollection<AnswerOption> AnswerOptions { get; set; } = new Collection<AnswerOption>();
    public ICollection<QuestionTag> QuestionTags { get; set; } = new Collection<QuestionTag>();
    public ICollection<QuestionCategory> QuestionCategories { get; set; } = new Collection<QuestionCategory>();
}
```

The `QuestionCategory` class has the property `Category` of type `Category`:

```
public class QuestionCategory : AuditEntity
{
    public long QuestionId { get; set; }
    public long CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Question Question { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}

public class Category : AuditEntity
{
    public long CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public long? ParentCategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category ParentCategory { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Category> ChildCategories { get; set; } = new Collection<Category>();
    public ICollection<QuestionCategory> CategoryQuestions { get; set; } = new Collection<QuestionCategory>();
}
```

Each `Category` has the property `ParentCategory` that is an object of type `Category`. So here I have a tree of categories whose branches have different lengths and are defined by users.

Currently, if there are just root categories and their child categories, I load a collection of questions in this way:

```
public class QuestionRepository : BaseRepository<Question>, IQuestionRepository
{
    protected override IQueryable<Question> DbQuery => base.DbQuery
        .Include(q => q.QuestionCategories).ThenInclude(qc => qc.Category).ThenInclude(c => c.ParentCategory);
```

However, if there is another nesting level, i.e. the above-mentioned child categories have their own children, I must add another `.ThenInclude()` statement:

```
public class QuestionRepository : BaseRepository<Question>, IQuestionRepository
{
    protected override IQueryable<Question> DbQuery => base.DbQuery
        .Include(q => q.QuestionCategories).ThenInclude(qc => qc.Category).ThenInclude(c => c.ParentCategory).ThenInclude(c => c.ParentCategory);
```

And so on...

The matter is that quantities of nesting levels are different for each `Question` and the quantity is not limited. So I should somehow calculate the number of `Category` levels for each `Question` and call `.ThenInclude()` for each level.

However, I have no idea how to implement that. Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you actually tried to access all levels, or did you just assume you'd have to have a variable amount of includes to achieve that?

At least in previous versions of EF, it was only necessary to include one level of a self-referential hierarchy. The query to pull in one level of a self-referential relationship actually has all the data necessary to wire up all levels of that relationship. Because of the way an ORM like EF works, once that data is available, it is possible to construct the entire object graph without having to explicitly issue further queries. I don't know for sure it still works this way in EF Core, but I don't see any reason why it shouldn't. The underlying principle of why it works remains the same in both.

Comment: Chris, it doesn't work in EFC (and never did in EF). The only way which works (and worked) is if you load the whole tree (table).

Comment: Chris, If I don't add a ThenInclude() statement for an additional nesting level, then its parent level's ParentCategory property has null in its value.